# How to check if a form submitted after a page refresh in jstl

Tags: java, jsp, jstl

I have a bean class which contains an ArrayList property called errorMessages. Here is my setter and getter.

```
    public ArrayList<String> getErrorMessages() {
        return errorMessages;
    }

    public void setErrorMessages(ArrayList<String> errorMessages) { 
        this.errorMessages = errorMessages;
    }
```

I'm using add() method to add associated error message where my other properties which are needed to validated. Like:

```
public void setNewPassword(String newPassword) {
    if(Validator.isPasswordValid(newPassword)) {
        this.newPassword = newPassword;
    } else {
        errorMessages.add("Password must be between 6-18 characters!");
    }
}
```

And my jsp page seems like:

```
<c:if test="${not empty param.signup}">
//some code...

    <c:if test="${not empty signup.errorMessages}">
        <div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert">
            <c:out value="Something went wrong. Check errors written below."/><br />
            <c:forEach items="${signup.errorMessages}" var="errors">
                <c:out value="- ${errors}" /><br />
            </c:forEach>
        </div>          
    </c:if>
<c:if>
```

So when I try to sign up and get some error on browser, error messages never disappear even though I refresh the page. I tried to set errorMessages property to null and check the form submitted or not. Neither works. The question seems basic but I couldn't find proper solution. Thank you in advance.

Edit: "signup" refers to bean object, created with page scope and I also tried request scope. Result is the same. Here's the code:

```
<jsp:useBean id="signup" class="myPackage.AccountManagerBeans" scope="page" />
```

Comment: Seems like you're storing the `errorMessages` in session scope while it should be stored in request scope.

Comment: `errorMessages` is not stored session scope, I edited the question.